# How/where to get jms jndi configuration values in jboss to configure in cast iron studio

Tags: jboss, cast-iron

Can anybody help me to configure jms jndi properties in Cast Iron studio for accessing jms queue. I'm using jboss. How/where to get jms jndi properties in jboss?  Also it's asking for jndi provider details such as username, password, provider name, value, and connection factory. Where to get these details?

Comment: you can do  that in the standalone.xml there are some default jndi config in there as examples

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <datasource jndi-name="java:/project name" pool-name="project namre" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@databaseIP port service name</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>username</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>10</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```